# Ng-repeat on directive creating duplicate DOM elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have directive that renders a d3 scatter-plot directive on the DOM. I also have an `ng-bind` bound to an `array` that lists the inputs provided for the given scatter-plot. Both of these elements, the scatterplot and inputs, are inside of a `span` with `ng-repeat`, like this:

```
<section>
    <h3>Saved Charts</h3>
        <div class="saved-charts-repeat" ng-repeat="s in savedCharts">
                <p ng-bind="s.input"></p>
                <scatter-template input="s.chart"></scatter-template>
        </div>
</section>
```

`savedCharts`, the array given to `ng-repeat` looks like this:

```
$scope.savedCharts = [
        {
            input: [[array], [array]], 
            chart: [{object}, {object}, {object}]
        },
        {
            input: [[array]], 
            chart: [{object}, {object}]
        }
 ];
```

`s.input` binds the array to the DOM, `s.chart` passes the chart objects to the `scatter-template` directive.

When I run this, the output looks like this:
[image: inputs repeating vertically, graph repeating horizontally]

The 'GW's are the `s.input` arrays (each of them is 1 array), in this case.

They should be inline and going across the page. I inspected the element, and found that all of the charts were appearing in the first instance of the `ng-repeat`, and the `s.input`s were being spread appropriately.

Look at the below from Chrome DevTools, the first instance of the wrapper, `.saved-charts-repeat` holds all of the charts, but only one of the inputs.

[image: showing positioning of element with all of the graphs]

Why are my inputs being spread out throughout the repeat, but my charts are being piled up in the first instance?

**Edit**

Here is my CSS

```
.saved-charts-repeat { //ngrepeat
  .inputs {
  }
  scatter-template {
    display: block;
  }
  svg {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    min-width: 320px;
  }
```

**Edit 2**

Here is a codepen that recreates my problem:
http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/pJwMEE

Comment: Can you post a link to some sort of full example? It could be a simplified jsFiddle or even the real thing. It's hard to tell if this is a CSS issue, a D3.js issue, or an actual AngularJS issue.

Comment: Alright, I put together a codepen that demonstrates my problem:
http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/pJwMEE

Comment: Perfect. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line of code in your directive:

```
var svg = d3.select('scatter-template')
```

`d3.select()` returns the first element that matches the selector. In this case, it returns the first `<scatter-template>` element in your repeater, which is why all of your SVGs end up in the first `<scatter-template>` element.

What you want to do is this:

```
var svg = d3.select(el[0])
```

`d3.select()` can also take a direct instance of an element. Angular's `link()` function in your directive receives a jQuery-wrapped instance of the directive element, so we can pass the raw element to D3 via `el[0]`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I had created a similar scatter plot in another directive, and thought it would save me time to copy and paste it into this new directive. It didn't save me time, and produced this headache. I never would have figured this out without your help.